# Gstreamer appsink playlist failed : Too many files

Tags: c++, opengl-es, gstreamer

I'm new to Gstreamer and I'm trying to make a playlist feature using Gstreamer on specified GLES window, these are my Pipeline elements:

```
gstPipeline     = gst_pipeline_new ("_pipeline");
data.source     = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc"   , "_source");
data.decoder    = gst_element_factory_make ("decodebin" , "_decoder");
data.qvconv     = gst_element_factory_make ("qvconv"    , "_qvconv");
data.capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "_capsfilter");
data.queue      = gst_element_factory_make ("queue"     ,"_queue");
data.sink       = gst_element_factory_make ("appsink"   , "_appsink");
```

I set callbacks by `gst_app_sink_set_callbacks(GST_APP_SINK(data.sink), &appsinkCallback, this, nullptr);`

In every EOS callback I do this(which I'm not sure it's the correct way) :

```
gst_element_set_state(gstPipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
g_object_set (data.source, "location", "/home/root/short.mp4", NULL);
gst_element_set_state(gstPipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

It worked, but only 27 times, at the 27th time of EOS, these error shows up and crashes my program.

```
GBM_ERR::msmgbm_bo_create(645)::ION_IOC_MAP failed on Metadata BO Err:
Too many open files
```

or sometimes

```
GBM_ERR::ion_open(118)::open /dev/ion failed!
Too many open files
GBM_ERR::msmgbm_device_create(1608)::Failed to open ION device
gbm_create_device(147): Device creation failed
```

this error doesn't show up if I change appsink to waylandsink, autovideosink etc. , and control callback with `msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus,GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, (GstMessageType)(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));`, but it creates a new window when playing a new video, which is not what I wanted.

1.What is causing the too many opened file error and how to fix it?

2.Is there a better way to make a playlist feature?

Lots of thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.
in my appsink, the information transforms like this :
GstSample -> GstBuffer -> GstIonBufFdMeta -> EGLImageKHR

the EGLImageKHR is not deleted after usage, so meta.fd(file descriptor) is continuously increasing.

I use eglDestroyImageKHR in EOS to manage ImageKHR and solved my problem.

There is also another way to complete playlist feature,
the "concat" element can concatenate videos after end of another.